# Need to Set Condition on Decision Element in Flow to Evaluate Case Records Last Modified More Than 5 Days Ago

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm trying to build out a flow that will update the case status if the Last Modified Date is Greater than 5 Days Ago.

Currently I'm using the following conditions:

[image]

Where the formula I'm evaluating is as follows:

[image]

However, I keep getting an error when saving that says, "RecordUpdateinLast5Days (Formula) - The formula expression is invalid."

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a SOQL relative date filter in a formula expression

```
{!$Record.LastModifiedDate} < LAST_N_DAYS:5
```

This is not allowed, you have to use expressions that you could use in a Validation Rule or Formula field

So, you'll need

```
DATEVALUE({!$Record.LastModifiedDate}) < (TODAY()-5)
```